# Loop through array and replace old with new

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I am trying to loop through an array and replace the old version with a new one.

My code Im using is:

```
db.cases.aggregate(
    { $match: { 'companyID': 218 }},
    { $unwind: '$cases' }, 
    { $group: { "_id": "$cases.casenumber", cases: {$push:'$cases'}, "count": { $sum:1 }}},
    { $match: { "count": { "$gt": 1 }}}
    { $project: { "cases": { $slice: [ "$cases", -1, { $subtract: [ { $size: "$cases" }, 1 ]}] }}},
    { $project: { "cases": { $arrayElemAt: ['$cases', 0] }}},
    { $group: { _id: 1, cases: {$push:'$cases' }}},
    { $out: 'cases' }
)
```

The problem is that $out just overwrites the cases document, however I want to keep the cases document and only update the specific cases array for the companyID inside the document.

Here is how the document looks:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide sample docs? Are duplicates identical on all fields? if not, how do you know which value you need to keep?

Comment: @Andrew : You should not be using $out just to update fields in docs in a collection, you need to be careful while using it, Are you updating that field across all docs in cases collection? If at all you've to use it give a different name like collection-new & rename it once everything looks good. Cause if you accidentally do a mistake in your aggregation then whole collection will be replaced, Also your query should create a new collection named `cases` if it's not there or replaces it if it's exists - is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: @matthPen So I pull data from another source to store in Mongodb as its faster to use mongo than constantly calling the other source. However if during the day someone changes the value of the type to 1 (in above image) and then I pull the information again how do i know its already in mongo and all that needs to be updated is the type field.